# Vaadin 14 style button in tab CSS

Tags: css, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

is teher any chance to style my button inside tab in the css for vaadin-tabs component or i must do it by setclassname individually for button?[image]

Accordin to this tutorial https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/styling-components
i tried:

```
vaadin-tabs vaadin-button{
   background-color:red;
}

vaadin-tab > vaadin-button{
   background-color:red;
}

[part="close-tab-btn"]{
  background-color:red;
}
```

But none of it work. I`m importing my css by annotation:

```
@CssImport(value="./styles/components/tabs.css", themeFor = "vaadin-tabs")
```

and rest of my css looks like this:

```
[part="tabs"] ::slotted(vaadin-tab[selected]) {
    color: var(--default-white-color);
    background-color: var(--default-black-color);
}

[part="tabs"] ::slotted(vaadin-tab) {
    color: var(--default-black-color);
    background-color: var(--default-white-color-2);
    border-radius: var(--default-border-radius) var(--default-border-radius) 0px 0px;
    MARGIN-RIGHT: 3px;

}

[part="tabs"] ::slotted(vaadin-tab[selected])::before{
    background-color: var(--default-app-color);
    width:100%
}
```

***edit**

But if my component is inside of dom in my slotted component then i can somehow style it from my top layout. In this example i mean if i can style input-field of text-area inside vaadin-vertical-layout

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of your screenshot, the `vaadin-button` is not inside any shadow root. In that case, you can style it from the global styles.

For example `styles.css`

```
vaadin-button.close-tab-btn {
  background-color: red;
}
```

and importing it with something like

`@CssImport("./styles/styles.css")`.

Comment: so then how can i change style for tabs that are not selected for this button?

Comment: And on this img i see that vaadin-tab is not in dom as well but still i can access it

Comment: You can do `vaadin-tab[selected] vaadin-button`, for example.

Comment: The `vaadin-tabs` component has a `<slot>` inside the shadow DOM, where it places the `vaadin-tab` element. Because of this, it ends up in the light DOM. However, you can also access it with `::slotted(...)` as you do. The `::slotted` selector can only be used to style the element inside the slot, not any of its children.

Comment: so if vaadin-button is slot of vaadin-tab which is slot of vaddin-tabs then i cant get it for vaadin-tabs?

Comment: Correct, you can't style it from `vaadin-tabs` styles.

Comment: but if it would be in dom inside of my vaadin-tab then how could i style it from vaadin-tabs?